# Centralised logger for multiple applications

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot

Is there any possibility to store logs from my different application may be in different languages can store logs in single file as per timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve and aggregate every application's logs in some kind of [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).

> Logstash is an open source, server-side data processing pipeline that ingests data from a multitude of sources simultaneously, transforms it, and then sends it to your favorite “stash.”

If you can force that every one of your applications outputs logs with the same pattern, I guess logstash (plus an elasticsearch or anything of its kind behind) would exactly answer your needs.